"You cannot engage in argument unless you rely on the principle of non-contradiction"
A very good SEoP article "Aristotle on Non-contradiction" by Paula Gottlieb makes two interesting claims, one after the other:
Claim 1: "Anyone asking for a deductive argument for PNC [the principle of non-contradiction], as Aristotle points out, is missing the point, or, rather, is asking for something that is impossible without using PNC."
Claim 2. "You cannot engage in argument unless you rely on PNC."
Here, Gottlieb is referring to the ontological principle of non-contradiction, which says that the same thing cannot have and not have the same thing at the same time.
Two questions.
Question 1: Aristotle and others seem to make arguments in favor of the truth of PNC with the following structure:
[Premise 1] If the PNC is false, then we would live in a world that differs from our own
[Premise 2] But we don't live in a world that differs from our own
[Conclusion] Therefore, the PNC is true
This is a modus tollens argument. Being the one who originally advanced Claim 1, I am sure that Aristotle did not think this sort of argument constituted an actual proof of PNC. But if Claim 1 is correct, then PNC ought to be "hidden" in the premises of this argument somewhere, right? My suspicion is that it is hidden in Premise 2, since the claim "we don't live in a world that differs from our own" seems to have the assumption that we live in our own world buried in it, so it seems to be logically equivalent to "we cannot live in our own world and not live in it at the same time," but I don't have the knowledge of first-order (or second?) logic that is required to confirm this. Is my suspicion correct?
Question 2: Where is PNC "hidden" in the following two very basic arguments?
[Premise] I am a person.
[Conclusion] Therefore, I am a person.
[Premise 1] If dogs are mammals, then dogs are animals.
[Premise 2] Dogs are mammals.
[Conclusion] Therefore, dogs are animals.
I don't see why we would need PNC to make these arguments. Thanks.

What does it mean for an an argument to be valid or invalid? Can an argument be both valid and invalid? The notion of making logical arguments while allowing contradictions seems silly.

As you say, the original argument uses modus tollens. But the PNC is not "hidden in the premises": modus tollens itself is a combination of modus ponens (from "if P then Q" we could deduce Q) and PNC (since not Q, we can't deduce Q from a true premise).
By contrast your other two arguments only use modus ponens, and so don't need PNC. I don't think the writer is saying you can't deduce anything without PNC, merely that you can't deduce anything interesting.

I am not quite sure I follow what you said in the first paragraph. I can see that modus tollens relies on a combination of modus ponens and contraposition. But I don't see why we need to rely on PNC to prove that P --> Q is equivalent to ~Q --> ~P. All you need is the principle of bivalence and a truth table.
(I can also see that LEM and LNC together imply that either P or Not-P must be true. If P is true, Q is true, and if ~P is true, Q or ~Q are true, so the only way ~Q can be true is if ~P is true. In other words, ~Q --> ~P. But you can get there with just bivalence, no?)

@logiclearner without PNC truth tables are not so simple. You can't just have a list of possible truth values for P and Q, since that won't allow you to deduce whether $\neg P$ and $\neg Q$ are true. It is possible without PNC to have a situation where P, Q and $\neg Q$ are all true, but $\neg P$ is not, showing that $P\to Q$ is not equivalent to $\neg Q\to \neg P$.

Let me first note that I shall take the question as is, and so, discuss neither the fidelity of the question to Gottlieb's article, nor Gottlieb's own analysis of Aristotle's views.
Aristotle argues that the principle of non-contradiction (PNC) is the ultimately firm and fundamental principle of all reasoning and rational thought. He considers the principle from various perspectives in which he spells it out; we may summarise his accounts symbolically as $\neg(P\wedge\neg P)$, or modally, $\forall x\forall F\neg\Diamond(Fx\wedge\neg Fx)$.
He holds that its truth must be presupposed in all forms of reasoning, particularly deductive arguments, where denying the conclusion while asserting the premisses would result in a contradiction. As such, PNC cannot be demonstrated because any demonstration of its truth would already rely on its validity, leading to a vicious circle.
Aristotle sees PNC as a comprehensive principle that applies universally to all things; but not to go off-topic, we shall focus on its role as a principle of reasoning (syllogistikē archē).
Though he says deductive reasoning (syllogismos) as well as scientific demonstration (apodeixis) rely on PNC, he does not specifically dwell on how we presuppose it in reasoning and demonstration. However, from his overall discussion, we understand the main idea: This is analogous to a competent speaker's grasp of the grammar of a natural language. Such a speaker tacitly knows and presupposes the grammar. But the presupposition manifests itself when an ungrammatical speech occurs (as a correction, an objection, etc.).
Likewise, PNC normally works in the background, and it explicitly comes to the fore when it is violated. Aristotle gives a succint description of what he sees as a valid argument in Prior Analytics as:

A syllogism [deduction] is a form of words [an argument] in which,
when certain assumptions [truth of premisses] are made, something
other than what has been assumed [the conclusion and its truth]
necessarily follows from the fact that the assumptions are such. By
'from the fact that they are such' I mean that it is because of them
that the conclusion follows; and by this I mean that there is no need
of any further term to render the conclusion necessary.

It is not expected for us to single out a statement in an argument as involving the PNC, rather, in view of the conception of a valid argument, to determine when a contradiction, whether deliberately (as in reductio ad absurdum) or not, occurs in the argument.
I recommend for those interested to glance over the Loeb Classical Library texts of Metaphysics and Prior Analytics.

Thank you for your answer. I interpret your answer as saying that, whether we like it or not, we all subconsciously rely on the PNC when we argue. So, while we may not be consciously thinking "Not-(P and Not-P)" all the time, our brain naturally chooses not to go somewhere in an argument if it's going to lead to a contradiction and we're always doing "did I contradict myself somewhere?" sanity checks.
So, putting my subconscious mind in brackets, and using my examples: "I am a person. (Uh, oh, I better not say that I am not a person. That'll be bad.) Therefore, I am a person."

We don't need to appeal to psychological models (consciousness/subconsciousness, etc.) here. Just consider the natural language analogy. Each time we speak, we conform to and confirm the grammar. The grammar pervades the speech; without grammar, hardly there is an intelligible speech. Indeed, Aristotle devotes the larger part of his discussion to explaining away the cases that the PNC seems to, or is claimed to, not hold. For a broader view of the matter, see A. Bardon's Transcendental Arguments.

In Principia Mathematica (1910-1913) the authors proved, from their own set of propositional axioms, the law P.2.08, called the "principle of identity":

p → p.

In P.2.11 they proved "excluded middle": ¬p ∨ p, and in P.3.24 the "law of contradiction": ¬(p∧¬p).
The result is obvious due to the fact that the conditional is not primitive in the Principia: p → q is defined as ¬p ∨ q in Def.1.01 (page 98).
In Begriffsschrift (1879) G,Frege proved the Prop.27 that in modern notation is A → A.
Frege comment is: "We cannot (at the same time) affirm A and deny A". This means that A → A is already the Excluded Middle.
For Frege, the conditional is primitive and it is elucidated through truth conditions: the conditional A → B "means that the possibility that A is affirmed and B is denied does not take place."
The above proofs, albeit formally correct, beg the question from an intuitive point of view.
Consider Frege's elucidation of A → B and apply it to A → A: "the possibility that A is affirmed and A is denied does not take place." But this is exactly LNC.
In Classical Logic the principle is there from the start, embedded into the truth-functional definition of connectives and in the assumption that there are two "logical objects": the truth values (see Frege again: the True (das Wahre) and the False (das Falsche)).
As you can see, LNC "was there from the start" not of mathematical logic, but of formal logic and (Western) philosophy.
See Aristotle's Metaphysics 1011b13:

Let this, then, suffice to show that the most indisputable of all beliefs is that contradictory statements are not at the same time true [...].

For a detailed account of LNC in Aristotle and A's attempted proofs, see Jan Lukasiewicz, On the Principle of Contradiction in Aristotle (1910) (The Review of Metaphysics, 1971)
